# iTextSharp send PDF as attachment using Memorystream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

been struggling with this and have gotten so close, but not quite there. I am trying to use iTextSharp V 4.1.2 to send a PDF as an email attachment. The code I provided below is using both filestream and memorystream, filestream is there to prove to myself that the PDF template is being stamped with data (it is). Also, I am receiving the email, but without an attachment. Can anyone see what I'm missing please?

```
public class BasePDFController : BaseController
```

{
    protected ActionResult eMailPdf(object model)
    {
        string pdf = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Infrastructure/PDFTemplates/fw9.pdf"));
        string outputFilePath = @"C:\Projects\Temp\test_template_filled.pdf";

```
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    PdfReader pdfFileReader = null;
    PdfReader pdfMemoryReader = null;

    try
    {
        pdfFileReader = new PdfReader(pdf);
        pdfMemoryReader = new PdfReader(pdf);

        using (FileStream pdfOutputFile = new FileStream(outputFilePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            PdfStamper pdfFileStamper = null;
            PdfStamper pdfMemoryStamper = null;
            try
            {
                pdfFileStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfFileReader, pdfOutputFile);
                pdfMemoryStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfMemoryReader, memoryStream);

                AcroFields acroFileFields = pdfFileStamper.AcroFields;
                AcroFields acroMemoryFields = pdfMemoryStamper.AcroFields;

                acroFileFields.SetField("topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_01_0_[0]", "Batman");

                pdfFileStamper.FormFlattening = true;
                pdfMemoryStamper.FormFlattening = true;
                pdfMemoryStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
                if (pdfMemoryStamper != null)
                {
                    pdfMemoryStamper.Close();
                }
                memoryStream.Position = 0;

                EmailProvider.Email email = new EmailProvider.Email();
                email = new EmailProvider.Email
                {
                    To = "someone@gamil.net",
                    Subject = "Scholars Attached PDF",
                    Body = "A PDF!",
                    Attachment = new Attachment(memoryStream, new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("application/pdf"))
                };
                EmailProvider.SendEmail(email);                    
                }
            finally
            {
                if (pdfFileStamper != null)
                {
                    pdfFileStamper.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        pdfFileReader.Close();
        pdfMemoryReader.Close();
    }
    return File(outputFilePath, "application/pdf", "Returned.pdf");
}
```

}

**EDIT:**
 - yes, there is a problem with the mail provider. I don't know how to fix it though, or if this is even the best way to go about sending? The person who wrote this obviously gave up.
**EDIT**
Fixed the attachment.

```
    public static class EmailProvider
{
    public class Email
    {
        public String To { get; set; }

        public String Subject { get; set; }

        public String Body { get; set; }

        **public Attachment Attachment { get; set; }**
    }

    public static void SendEmail(Email email)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add(email.To);
        mail.Subject = email.Subject;
        mail.Body = email.Body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Attachments.Add(email.Attachment);
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
}
```

With the email fixed, I am receiving the PDF! However, when I try to open the PDF from email I get an error:
There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired.
Ideas?

Comment: The issue may be with `EmailProvider.Email` or `EmailProvider.SendEmail`. Post that code if you can.

Comment: I have updated the code above, if anyone is looking for a working example of mailing a PDF using iTextSharp, the example above works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `pdfMemoryStamper.Close()` after `pdfMemoryStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;`

Like this:

```
// *snip*

pdfFileStamper.FormFlattening = true;
pdfMemoryStamper.FormFlattening = true;
pdfMemoryStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;

pdfMemoryStamper.Close();

memoryStream.Position = 0;

// *snip*
```